# Deconstruct nested parameters with typescript and default values

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

If I had the following in javascript:

```js
//deconstructed
({ theme: { colors: { border = '#cccccc' } = {} } = {} } => border)

//Creating similar with nested params
//Optional Chaining
props?.theme?.colors?.border ?? '#cccccc' 

//bog standard js
props.theme && props.theme.colors ? props.theme.colors.border : '#cccccc'
```

Here is what I have managed to get so far with `typescript`

```js
(props:Props, { theme: { colors: { border = '#cccccc' } = {} } = {} }: { theme: Object }) => border
```

But this falls over with:

```js
TypeScript error in /var/www/poc/src/components/text-input/text-input.tsx(53,17):
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject, ...interpolations: SimpleInterpolation[]): FlattenSimpleInterpolation', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimpleInterpolation'.
      Type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'FlattenSimpleInterpolation': concat, join, slice, indexOf, and 17 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemeProps<any>>, ...interpolations: Interpolation<ThemeProps<any>>[]): FlattenInterpolation<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemeProps<any>>'.
      Type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemeProps<any>>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Props, any>>, ...interpolations: Interpolation<...>[]): FlattenInterpolation<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Props, any>>'.
      Type '(props: Props, { theme: { colors: { border } } }: { pretty: Object; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Props, any>>'.  TS2769

    51 | /* css border variants (this is an example of splitting up styles a bit more than the example in StyledLabel) */
    52 | const normalBorder = css`
  > 53 |     1px solid ${(props:Props, { theme: { colors: { border = '#cccccc' } = {} } = {} }: { theme: Object }) => border};
       |                 ^
    54 | `;
    55 | 
    56 | const errorBorder = css`
```

Comment: Your typescript example [does not seem to do what you want it to, syntactically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=83&pln=1&pc=1#code/BQbwBALgFgpgtjAXGcBjA9gG3QJwM7LgBGuAJjDmALxgDkAxKk87WAL7Uocc0jfUA+MCRzkcASgBQQA). [This version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBARg9gTgExHAXBAzmOBLAdgcwG4AoACgG8IwALEAWxDUoGMZh50np4k4IBeCAHIAxM3EShEAL4CI5WbMEKZASmKtc6NiAB07fKViJkqwkA) seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks!! Though the example doesn't seem to running a function. Which i where some of my confusion comes from.

Comment: Why not just use optional chaining in TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example of destructured parameters with default values:

```
const myFn = ({ theme: { colors: { border = '#cccccc' } = {} } = {} } = {}) => border

myFn() // #cccccc
myFn({}) // #cccccc
myFn({ theme: {} }) // #cccccc
myFn({ theme: { colors: {} } }) // #cccccc
myFn({ theme: { colors: { border: '#000000' } } }) // #000000

// Not sure, how your `props` are related to the theme object, so I omitted them here
```

Destructuring assignments can really become hard to read with deeply nested structures. It even becomes more complex, when you give explicit types to `myFn` or parameters:

```
type Themeable = {
    theme?: {
        colors?: {
            border?: string
        }
    }
}

const myFn = ({ theme: { colors: { border = '#cccccc' } = {} } = {} }: Themeable = {}) 
  => border
```

[TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#function-declarations) advise to keep them as simple as possible or manually write the assignments for better readability:

> Use destructuring with care. As the previous example demonstrates, anything but the simplest destructuring expression is confusing. This is especially true with deeply nested destructuring, which gets really hard to understand even without piling on renaming, default values, and type annotations. Try to keep destructuring expressions small and simple. You can always write the assignments that destructuring would generate yourself.

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFhAthAhgIwDbQLxQN4BQUxUwCyA-AFz5En0DGA9hkwE4DO1t9vJa7ACYQ23DsDYBLAHYBzOnwC+CqMuUFm08VEQgAYtKi4AFHlLkINM81acrUAW2FsjUAOQBiBt59vVrvEV-XEDVGngkVEwcfEUASiMAPgchEQICXQNjBIB6HKgvH28M-WlTeKg8gqLizLKzMkirIIqqwqKSrIaLext2Dmb-Vvz2n0768yb8KD67acdnGk8ABlW1vxbVXJG1taA)

Comment: I see! You can provide TS an object as a variables but tell TS the type of this variable. My lord potatoe!! Thank you

Comment: lol i bloody love renaming them!! Curse TS!!!! Thats what I say lol

Comment: I thought I would ask ford04, do you have any idea about these items?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604744/using-typescript-with-material-ui-makestyles-webhook

Comment: no, not sure about the types used in that lib (you might create a sandbox to get better help in that question).